# How to communicate with socket cluster server with python as client

Tags: python-2.7, socket.io, ubuntu-14.04

I am Newbie to SocketCluster i had install the socketcluster with help of link

> http://socketcluster.io/#!/docs/getting-started

I am able to communicate with server through browser console as given in above link.But i want the python as client.

So for this i try using SocketIO pacakage. Following is **my code**

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
with SocketIO('localhost', 8000) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit("ping", {message: ' object with a message property'})
```

But i am **getting error** as

> **No handlers could be found for logger "socketIO_client"**

So i want to know how to communicate with SocketCluster server with python as client

Answer (score 3):

The Socket.io client is not protocol-compatible with the SocketCluster server. SC sockets do share a similar API as Socket.io though. There is no Python client for SC at the moment.

Comment: Hmm.. it doesn't look like socketcluster.io document their protocol anywhere. At least socket.io protocol is documented (https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io-protocol). So implementing a python socketcluster client library requires reverse-engineering socketcluster client code.